# Migration ms access to SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Migration data was hard but finished.
My problem is to conversion working ms access code to working SQLite code.

So I need to call SQLite db from MS office over ODBC driver, and that option goes ok.
Right now I have problem with selection few cell for ex. this code working ok with access db:

SQLQuery "SELECT [X] & 'adress:' & [Y] FROM [mytable] WHERE [Z]='"test"'", strFilePath, blnReturn, varArray

I get working version only with one selection:
SQLQuery "SELECT [X] FROM [mytable] WHERE [Z]='" test "'", strFilePath, blnReturn, varArray

Any idea how to solve this issue?
Thx.

Comment: Replace `&` with `||`.

Comment: Thx for avice I will try.One more question, in real life full function use SELECT RIGHT('00000',[B],6) so is it possible to add same function in SQL , I try many option but all time I get error ODBC driver not support.thx in advance.

Comment: THX I try replay  || and working good. Thx again. Pls advice for select right!?

Comment: FYI,I found solution SELECT SUBSTR ('000000',B,6) thx, issue closed!!